How can I convert Gradio app to flask api?
I am trying to convert Gradio app to flask api.
In Gradio app, it is using components like Image, Text, and so on.
I have to change that component to request form data.
However, I am suffering with image processing.
I need any help.
This is my code.
cloth_image = gr.Image(label="Your label...", type="pil") cloth_mask_image = gr.Image(label="Your label...", type="pil")
How can I get the same return value as gr.Image component by preprocessing of cloth_image = request.files['cloth_image']

what you get in cloth_image?  If it is pil image then you can get request.files['cloth_image'] and use io.BytesIO() to create file-like object in memory and use it Image.open(). You may see it in many Flask examples which need to process uploaded images.

I think gr.Image component returns the numpy value for give image. And I need to get the same result as the gr.Image components returns.

Your code shows type="pil" so I expected that you need pillow but in answer I show also how to convert pillow to numpy - arr = numpy.array(pil_image)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you need image (as PIL) only on server then you can use directly
from PIL import Image

cloth_image = Image.open( request.files["cloth_image"] )

Because files["cloth_image"] has method .read() so it can be treated as file-like object, and Image.open() can use file-like object instead of filename.
And you can convert between pillow and numpy(and opencv)
# from pillow to numpy/opencv
arr = numpy.array(cloth_image)

# from numpy/opencv to pillow
cloth_image = Image.fromarray(arr)

(opencv may need to convert colors between RGB and BGR)

Minimal working code:
from flask import Flask, request
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "cloth_image" in request.files:
            img = request.files["cloth_image"]  # it has method .read() so it can be treated as file-like object
            cloth_image = Image.open(img)  # it can use file-like object instead of filename
            # ... process image ...

    return """
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="cloth_image">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

But if you need to send it back then you may need to use io.BytesIO to save image in file-like object in memory, convert it to base64, and display it as
html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(data)

More complex code which gets image, draw rectangle and send it back to browser.
from flask import Flask, request
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import io
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    img = 'empty'
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "image" in request.files:
            print(request.files)

            # get image
            img = request.files["image"]   # it has method .read()

            # read to pillow
            image = Image.open(img)

            # draw something
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)                                      # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html
            draw.rectangle([(20,20), (280,280)], outline=(255,0,0), width=3)  # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle
            draw.text((15,5), "Hello World!")                                 # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text

            # convert to file-like data
            obj = io.BytesIO()             # file in memory to save image without using disk  #
            image.save(obj, format='png')  # save in file (BytesIO)                           # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save
            obj.seek(0)

            # convert to bases64
            data = obj.read()              # get data from file (BytesIO)
            data = base64.b64encode(data)  # convert to base64 as bytes
            data = data.decode()           # convert bytes to string

            # convert to <img> with embed image
            img = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(data)

    return '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="image"><button type="submit">Send</button></form><br>' + img

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


And if you need it without reloading page then you may have to use JavaScript. But I skip this problem.
